# Errno::ENOENT for cache file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have the next code for cache:

```rb
Rails.cache.fetch('ham_response_fids', expires_in: 1.minutes, race_condition_ttl: 10.seconds) do
  # code omitted
end
```

And from time to time I am getting the next error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/deployer/apps/fids/releases/20190604090924/tmp/cache/70A/380/.permissions_check.70228682401260.18260.410918
```

I have no idea why it happens.
It happens not every time but quite often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the root of this problem. But I resolved it with change a cache storing from files to Memcache.